# is there any shortcut to turn on hotspot?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, hot-spot

is there any shortcut to turn on hot-spot. Its to long procedure to turn on hot-spot. Its my daily need procedure. Please suggest me any short cut to turn on/off hot-spot directly.

Comment: What's your Operating System??

Comment: I used Ubuntu 20.04